# How to mock each and every instance of a class

Tags: java, mocking, powermock, easymock

I want to mock my java class in such a ways so that each and every new instance of it should return the mocked response.

Comment: you could name the class AlwaysMocked

Comment: May be you should create a factory class with a getInstance() method and return a mock object from this method. Instead of calling new, call the getInstance() that will always return a mock object.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mocking libraries which support this: PowerMock (as shown in Matthias' answer), and JMockit.

In the second case, the test only needs to declare a mock field or mock parameter using the `@Mocked` annotation.

Comment: I am not familiar with `JMockit`, but I would expect that using `@Mocked` on an delared mock field, will create one mocked instance that's assigned to the field. It would be surprised, if it would "intercept" a call `new MyOriginalClass()` to create a mocked object instead.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Once a class is `@Mocked`, all of its instances are mocked; simple as that. The instance that gets created and assigned to the mock field (or test method parameter) is a *representative* of all such instances, for the purposes of recording and/or verifying expectations. So, a `new MyOriginalClass()` constructor execution does get "intercepted", but that *is* the mocked instance itself, no need to create another.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

It's basically:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(MyOriginalClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(new MyMockClass());
```

You also need to use `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`
 and `@PrepareForTest(ClassThatCallsConstructorOfMyOriginalClass.class)` as class annotation of you JUnit test class. If you have multiple classes that instantiate `MyOriinalClass` you can also specify whole packages:  `@PrepareForTest("com.mypackage.*")`